# Map data structure for lua like javascript has?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I need a lua data structure that works like javascripts Map(), is there some way?

As a bad solution, I've been maintaining two tables, one ordered table and one unordered table under `mytable` for this so far, and maintaining them both. So when I need to remove or add a key from one table, I need to also do that to the other table.

This way I can use mytable.unordered for fast existence checks

`mytable.unordered[key]`

and `mytable.ordered` for iteration (which has to be in order for my use case).

Comment: In what order? How do you define order for keys that don't have an order?

Comment: Insertion order @NicolBolas

Comment: `maintaining two tables` - Why do you call it a "bad solution"?